# Scipy 2D-FFT gives weird/wrong phases (Example of 2D-Ring Model)

Tags: python, scipy

I have a problem with getting the right phase information out of the 2D fast-fourier transform (2D-FFT) with scipy.

I have already found similar questions/solutions, which have been insightful, but have not been yielding the right answer for me.

In the following I will showcase my code and my thought behind it and I hope somebody can help me.

My code is split up on multiple files, but here are the in my opinion relevant sections from it that can be combined in a file and executed to show the output, for readability's sake I left them split up

First of all I set up a 2D-radial grid with a pixel scaling that is unit/px:

```py
import numpy as np

from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional, Union


def set_size(mas_size: int, size: int,
             incline_params: List[float] = None,
             sampling: Optional[int] = None) -> np.array:
    """Sets the size of the model and returns a 2D-radial grid

    Parameters
    ----------
    mas_size: int
        Sets the size of the images [mas] and implicitly the pixels
    size: int
        Sets the range of the model grid and implicitly the x-, y-axis.
    incline_params: List[float]
        A list of the inclination parameters [axis_ratio, pos_angle] [mas, rad]
    sampling: int, optional
        The pixel sampling

    Returns
    -------
    radius: np.array
        The 2D-radius grid
    """
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        fov_scale = mas_size/size

        if sampling is None:
            sampling = size

        x = np.linspace(-size//2, size//2, sampling, endpoint=False)*fov_scale
        y = x[:, np.newaxis]

        axis_ratio, pos_angle = incline_params[0], np.radians(incline_params[1])

        xr, yr = -x*np.cos(pos_angle)+y*np.sin(pos_angle), \
                 (x*np.sin(pos_angle)+y*np.cos(pos_angle))/axis_ratio

        return np.sqrt(xr**2+yr**2), fov_scale
```

Then I plug this into a function for a ring, for example

```
def ring(axis_ratio: float, pos_angle: int, mas_size: int, px_size: int,
                   sampling: Optional[int] = None,
                   inner_radius: Optional[int] = None,
                   outer_radius: Optional[int] = None) -> np.array:
        """Evaluates the model

        Parameters
        ----------
        axis_ratio: float, optional
            The ratio that determines ellipse (>1.) or ring (=1.)
        pos_angle: int | float, optional
            The angle of rotation of the model image
        mas_size: int
            Sets the size of the images [mas] and implicitly the pixels
        px_size: int
            The size of the model image
        sampling: int, optional
            The sampling of the object-plane
        inner_radius: int, optional
            A set inner radius overwriting the sublimation radius

        Returns
        --------
        model: np.array
        """
        radius, fov_scale = set_size(mas_size, px_size,[axis_ratio, pos_angle], sampling)                             

        if inner_radius:
            radius[radius < inner_radius] = 0.
        else:
            radius[radius < 1.] = 0.

        if outer_radius:
            radius[radius > outer_radius] = 0.

        if inner_radius:
            radius[np.where(radius != 0)] = 1/(2*np.pi*inner_radius)
        else:
            radius[np.where(radius != 0)] = 1/(2*np.pi)

        return radius, fov_scale
```

And I then do the FFT of this in the following way

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.fft import ifftshift, fftshift, fftfreq, fft2

model, fov_scale = ring(1.5, 135, 10, 2**9, inner_radius=1., outer_radius=1.1)

model_centre =  model.shape[0]//2

# Zero padding-order of 3
zero_padding = 2**int(np.log2(model.shape[0]) + 3)

freq_axis = fftshift(fftfreq(zero_padding, fov_scale))

# Scale by the wavelength of your model
freq_scaling_m = np.diff(freq_axis)[0]*8e-6

padded_image = np.zeros((zero_padding, zero_padding))
pad_centre = padded_image.shape[0]//2
mod_min, mod_max = pad_centre-model_centre, pad_centre+model_centre

padded_image[mod_min:mod_max, mod_min:mod_max] = model

ft = fftshift(fft2(ifftshift(padded_image)))
amp, phase = abs(ft), np.angle(ft, deg=True)

fig, (ax, bx, cx) = plt.subplots(1, 3)
ax.imshow(model)
bx.imshow(amp)
cx.imshow(phase)
plt.show()
```

And finally, here the plotted output images with the left being the object plane image (the model), the middle one being the amplitude of the FFT (normed) and the right most one being the phase space of the FFT:

*2D-FFT of Ring*
[image: 2D-FFT of Ring]

If I am not completely mistaken then the phase information should have circles that have either +180° or -180° and should not have mixed degrees circles...

Is there any glaring error here or do I have a wrong mindset about what the phase should look like for the FFT?

Thank you everyone for your help already!

**PS**: An additional question I have would be, does anyone know where there are good repositories or similar that show 2D-FFTs of various images (e.g., a Ring, Gaussian, etc.) or at least what the phases of a 2D-FFT of a 2D-Gaussian should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! It now shows the proper phase information.

[image: Proper Phase space of Model]

I switched from

```
from scipy.fft import ifftshift, fftshift, fftfreq, fft2
```

to

```
from numpy.fft import ifftshift, fftshift, fftfreq, fft2
```

I have found some other questions that show some people delving into the differences of the `numpy` and `scipy` implementation

[What is the difference between numpy.fft and scipy.fftpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363154/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-fft-and-scipy-fftpack)

**However, not really the reason for the difference. Will get back to this question when/if I find it.**

**PS**: Not specifically relevant in my case as I did this already, but for the FFT in numpy it is important that the axis are (non-)periodic, depending on the application, thus in this line

```
x = np.linspace(-size//2, size//2, sampling, endpoint=False)*fov_scale
```

Especially, the `endpoint=False`, which removes the endpoint from the x-axis. For more detailed information see:
[extracting phase information using numpy fft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36019736/19314661)
and
[Scipy FFT - how to get phase angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454723/scipy-fft-how-to-get-phase-angle)

And also it is important to shift the image/object to be Fourier transformed to the 0th space, as `numpy` (at least, don't know about scipy, shall look into it) needs the 0th element at the 0th index (or (0,0) for 2D). This is done with ifftshift (shift the 0th element to the 0st place and then shift it back to display it with fftshift):

```
ft = fftshift(fft2(ifftshift(padded_image)))
```

For a more detailed explanation see,
[Discrete Fourier Transform: How to use fftshift correctly with fft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743769/discrete-fourier-transform-how-to-use-fftshift-correctly-with-fft)

PPS: A more general (mathematical) explanation of how the phase comes into play in a FFT can be found here:
[numpy-fft-what-is-the-return-value-amplitude-phase-shift-or-angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618591/numpy-fft-what-is-the-return-value-amplitude-phase-shift-or-angle)